# Solving $ab-c+2^x=2^xd$ for $x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to solve for $x$ in this equation:
$$ab-c+2^x=2^xd$$
I've been trying to use Maple to figure it out but to no avail.

Looking for the mathematical solution and if possible a way to get the step-by-step solution in Maple also.

[image]

Comment: Subtract $2^x$ from both sides, and divide both sides by $d-1$? Then take a logarithm?

Comment: You might need to solve a variable first, as thats what it says on there.

Comment: @angryavian, thanks, sorry may not have been clear but I need to solve for x, if i subtract 2^x from both sides what happens to the x then?

Comment: On the left, the $2^x$ goes away.  On the right, since you have $d$ copies of $2^x$ and you are subtracting one, you now have $d - 1$ copies of it.  So, on the right you have $2^x(d - 1)$.  If you divide both sides by $(d - 1)$, that leaves $2^x$ on the right-hand side.  If you take the base 2 logarithm, that will leave just $x$.

Comment: @johnny, thanks a lot

Comment: If $d = 1$, then any value of $x$ will satisfy the equation, as long as $ab - c = 0.$  So, if $d = 1$ and $ab - c \neq 0$, then there are no solutions.  Beyond this, the already posted comments pertain **if and only if** $$\frac{ab - c}{d-1} ~~\text{is positive},$$ since $2^x$ must be a positive number, for any value of $x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\begin{align} &ab-c+2^x=2^xd\\ &\Rightarrow{ab-c}=2^{x}\left({d-1}\right)\\ &\Rightarrow{2^{x}}=\left(\frac{ab-c}{d-1}\right)\\&\Rightarrow{x}=\log_2\left(\frac{ab-c}{d-1}\right)\end{align}$$

The main conditions are:
$$
{d}\neq{1},\quad\left(\frac{ab-c}{d-1}\right)\gt{0}.
$$

Good luck!